# Error EOF inside action Flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am creating a file that will be compiled with flex, but I am having trouble understanding why I am getting this error. I am inexperienced with this.
The error says line 43 (ie the last line) end of file inside the action.
What I have so far.

```
%{
#ifdef PRINT
#define TOKEN(t) printf("Token: " #t "/n");
#else
#define TOKEN(t) return(t);
#endif
%}

%%
"," TOKEN(COMMA")
";" TOKEN(SEMICOLON)
"->"    TOKEN(ARROW)
"(" TOKEN(BRA)
")" TOKEN(KET)
"=" TOKEN(EQUALS)
"<>"    TOKEN(LESMORE)
 "<" TOKEN(LESS)_THAN)
 ">" TOKEN(MORE_THAN)
 "<="    TOKEN(LESS_EQUAL)
 ">="    TOKEN(MORE_EQUAL)
 "*" TOKEN(MULTIPLY)
 "/"    TOKEN(DIVIDE)
 "'"    TOKEN(CHAR_SHOW)
 ENDP    TOKEN(ENDP)
 DECLARATIONS    TOKEN(DECLARATIONS)
 CHARACTER   TOKEN(CHARACTER)
 INTEGER TOKEN(INTEGER)
 REAL    TOKEN(REAL)
 ENDIF   TOKEN(ENDIF)
 ELSE    TOKEN(ELSE)
 ENDDO   TOKEN(ENDDO)
 WHILE   TOKEN(WHILE)
 DO  TOKEN(DO)
 ENDWHILE    TOKEN(ENDWHILE)
 FOR TOKEN(FOR)
 IS  TOKEN(IS)
 BY  TOKEN(BY)
 TO  TOKEN(TO)
 ENDFOR  TOKEN(ENDFOR)
 WRITE   TOKEN(WRITE)
 NEWLINE TOKEN(NEWLINE)
 READ    TOKEN(READ)
 %%
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first action is:

```
"," TOKEN(COMMA")
```

which has a mismatched quote.

Also, there is a problem with

```
 "<" TOKEN(LESS)_THAN)
```

And it is not clear to me if all the lines from that one down are incorrectly indented by one space; if so, that is also a problem.

Finally, there is very little point in that `TOKEN` macro (which is probably copied from somewhere else where it is unnecessary) because you can use the [`--debug` command-line option](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) to Flex to produce very accurate scanner traces, and there is a similar [tracing facility in bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) which will also reveal the result of the scanner (including the name of the token, which the flex trace does not, unfortunately, provide).

Comment: Thank you yes the quote and misplaced bracket and lining up with tabbing got it compiling thank you. Sometimes these things are invisible when looking too hard.

Comment: @QFuullY: Lining up with tabs is not necessary, but it  is essential that every *pattern* start at the very beginning of the line, without any space.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Typos, you have to change that to :

```
            Line 10 :         "," TOKEN(COMMA")       -->     "," TOKEN(COMMA)

            Line 17:          "<" TOKEN(LESS)_THAN)   -->     "<" TOKEN(LESS_THAN)
```

Comment: Yes this and proper tabbing fixed it